# Returning data from directive template component to global $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

What I want to achieve is to create a component consisting of a dropdown list of dynamically populated checkboxes. - DONE

These checkboxes should fetch the names for the values inside the directive from an attribute `property-name` of a directive element. - DONE

They need to return the values (which of them are selected) to a variable in `$scope` which name is the same as the attribute `my-model` so I could read it from the main page referencing to `$scope.firstTitle` and  `$scope.secondTitle` as in plunker. - This is my problem

The most important part is that the solution should allow to insert many components on the same page without the variable in `$scope` of the previous component be overwritten by next one.

I've tried searching for an answer but none seem to address my exact issue which is populating values from one source to a template and passing the values from template to `$scope`.

Here's a plunker of what I've already achieved: https://plnkr.co/edit/Uwarzh7qxrE3pDKxH2u8?p=preview

HTML:

```
   <div ng-app="testModule" ng-controller="componentsController">

      <div class="container col-md-3">
        <mydropdown property-name="First Title" my-model="firstTitle"></mydropdown>
      </div>

      <div class="container col-md-3">
        <mydropdown property-name="Second Title" my-model="secondTitle"></mydropdown>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="testSave()">Test data output</button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('testModule', [])
    .controller('componentsController', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.testSave = function() {
            console.log($scope);
        }

    }])
    .directive('mydropdown', function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                propertyName: '@',
                myModel:'='
            },
            templateUrl: 'component.html',

            link: function (scope) {

              // this will be replaced with call to service
                scope.dropDowns = [
                    {
                        value: 'test1',
                        text: 'Test1'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'test2',
                        text: 'Test2'
                    }
                ];
            }
        }
    });
```

Component.html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="pull-left">{{propertyName}}</span>
        <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="dropDown in dropDowns">
            <div class="checkbox col-md-12">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dropDown.value"> {{dropDown.text}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: The `firstTitle` variable isn't set or read by the parent controller. The `myModel` variable inside the directive isn't used at all. There has been no attempt to connect this component to a data model. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component Based Archictecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) for the basics of connecting components.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your desired outcome? I have two combos with checkboxes - what do you exactyly want to happen when a checkbox is checked? Do you want something to be propagated to `componentsController`? Provide steps (from the user perspective) and the expected result. For now it's not exactly clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @jannis yes I wanted to propagate data to $scope, also georgeawg understood my intentions perfectly in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the model in the main controller:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.firstDropdowns = [
    {
      value: 'test1',
      text: 'Test1'
    },
   {
      value: 'test2',
      text: 'Test2'
    }
  ];
})
```

Connect with the component in the template:

```
   <mydropdown  my-model="vm.firstDropdowns">
   </mydropdown>
```

Use one-way `&` binding in the component:

```
app.component('mydropdown', {
    bindings: {
        myModel: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <div ng-repeat="dropDown in $ctrl.myModel">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dropDown.value" />
            {{dropDown.text}}
        </div>
    `
})
```

Because the input is an object, the `ng-model` directives inside the component will update the contents of the object and changes will be seen by the parent controller.

---

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])

.controller("mainCtrl", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.firstDropdowns = [
    {
      value: 'test1',
      text: 'Test1'
    },
   {
      value: 'test2',
      text: 'Test2'
    }
  ];
})

.component('mydropdown', {
    bindings: {
        myModel: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <div ng-repeat="dropDown in $ctrl.myModel">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dropDown.value" />
            {{dropDown.text}}
        </div>
    `
})
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
    <fieldset>
       <mydropdown  my-model="vm.firstDropdowns">
       </mydropdown>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <div ng-repeat="x in vm.firstDropdowns">
        {{x.value}} {{x.text}}
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
```

Comment: Looks like I was not far away from minimal-effort solution but your answer presented me a few new tricks such as the `component` command which I was unaware of. Thank you!

Comment: Components were introduced with AngularJS V1.5 as way to prepare developers for a smoother transition to Angular 2+ in the future. See [AngularJS Guide - Migrating to V1.5](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-4-to-1-5) and [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).